# how to backup a project on tfs 2010

Tags: .net, tfs

i am facing problem in backup tfs 201. 
Can we take a single project backup on TFS 2010.
Does any one know for the single project by the tfs 10?

Answer (score 0):

Backing up a single project was never a supported option with TFS. There are too many dependencies in the database.

Of course you can backup the whole project collection (which you hopefully do already regularly). If you want to look at an older state of the project, you will have to restore the whole collection backup to another instance of TFS. You can use the same database server, you just need an additional, independent application tier (with its own, new TFS configuration database).

If you want to restore bits of an older project state into the current instance, do the restore as mentioned above, then transfer what you need. Source code through the file system, WorkItems can often be transferred quite nicely with the "Open Query in Excel" feature, though you don't get access to all WI-columns that way (links don't work, for example).

Comment: Thanks                                                                                                           IS it possible 2010 TFS backup without network path i.e. local drive or USB hard disk?

Comment: While backup/restore is easiest with the TFS wizard (which requires a network share), nothing stops you from doing a normal SQL Server backup on a local drive. On the other hand, creating a share on the local drive should be easy, too.

Comment: If you are doing a manual backup make sure that you use named transaction logs. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253070(v=vs.120).aspx